# Geometric interpretation of Linear Independence and absolute value

Tags: linear-algebra

I am wondering something in regard to linear independence / dependence of functions.

I understand when working with vectors in $\mathbb{R^n}$ for example, we can make the geometric link that vectors in $R^{2}$ are dependent if they are able to be on the same line, and in $R^{3}$ if on the same plane.

For functions, how can we think of this? For example,

consider $f(x)=x^{3}$ and $g(x)=|x|^{3}$

Do we have to look at all points? for example to the left of the origin, it appears that we could have a scalar multiple of one function into the other, but on the right we cannot, thus would this imply independence over the whole space?

Also is the best way to test for linear independence/dependence with absolute value is to just pick a few points and see, or should we always use a geometric approach?

Thank you

Comment: A possibly useful observation: One should first fixed the function space. For example, for the two function you gave we have $f,g \in C^0 ( \mathbb{R} )$, however $f \in C^{\omega} \left( \mathbb{R} \right)$ whereas $g$ is not. So when restricting the function space to $C^{\omega}$, we can't even talk about linear independence of the two functions. I imagine that a geometric interpretation becomes clearer if you choose a more restrictive function space.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with that type of notation, can you tell me where I can find out more about it?

Comment: I see. Well let me just give the set definition. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $C^n \left( \mathbb{R} \right) := \{ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ~ | ~ f ~ \text{is } n \text{ times continuously differentiable} \}$. So $C^0$ is continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Now $C^{\omega}$ is the set of [analytic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. There is also the set $C^{\infty} \left( \mathbb{R} \right)$, smooth functions. All these sets are functions spaces.

Comment: So to say a bit more in relation to your question, we have that $f,g$ are linear dependent when regarded as functions from $(0, \infty)$, i.e., they are linearly dependent in $C^0 \left( (0,\infty) \right)$. However, they are not linearly dependent in $C^0 \left( \mathbb{R} \right)$. How you interpret this geometrically, I am not sure. $C^0$ is a "big" space. Try thinking of linearly independence geometrically in $P_n$, the space of real-valued polynomials of degree less that or equal to $n$.